# Persist Observable Object Among Multiple Activities

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp, rx-android

Consider this scenario : There are two activities Activity A do network call and display count of tasks and the Activity B fetch tasks from database, or from same network API call if data is not available. While A is busy in network call user can traverse to Activity B. I am using **Retrofit2** and **Rxjava2**.

My question is when Activity A is doing network call and user go to Activity B, and still the network call is running then, I want the object of Observable<> created on Activity A,also on Activity B because if I do not get callback then another network call for same task would be done on Activity B which is not feasible.

Anyone have idea How I can persist object of Observable<> created on Activity A ,by using this observable object I will get callback on Activity A as well as on Activity B and do some functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Seems what you like is to do work in the background, that will be accessible to a different parts of your app (`Activity`), in this case you might want to consider using an Android`Service`.
In short create a `Service` from `ActivityA` that will trigger fetching the data, then in the `ActivityB` connect to this `Service` to get an `Observable` with the data fetched in `ActivityA`.

For persisting the data and avoid making 2 calls to the same API, you can use operators like `cache()` that will multicast your `Observable` and cache the data, and then it can be available to `ActivityB` as well.

Another option as suggested is to hold a `static` reference to the `Observable`   or reference at `Application` level, that will be available to your entire app, but then you should be careful with leaks as detailed by @Blackbelt.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is when Activity A is doing network call and user go to
>   Activity B, and still the network call is running then,

You should unsubscribe the observable in order to cancel the network call. If you keep a strong reference to it, you will leak the activity for the time the network call runs. You should decouple this logic

> I want the
>   object of Observable<> created on Activity A,also on Activity B
>   because if I do not get callback then another network call for same
>   task would be done on Activity B which is not feasible

It is feasible. You could have a singleton, or better use `Dagger` to do that, that handles the network call, and emits the result to a `BehaviourSubject` to which you will subscribe. The nice thing of `BehaviourSubject` is that the latest value will always be emitted 
 to new subscribers.